# How to make HTML canvas fill the browser window?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I have a design that has a vertical wavy path. I'm trying to make it through **HTML canvas**. I have followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43KogUmZvcc) which makes a horizontal wave. But since I need vertical, I have tried to change the code a bit. 
This is what I tried so far:

```
<canvas #canvasElement></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.createCanvas();
}

createCanvas() {
   const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
   let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
   let curveDistance = 200; // Say the diameter of the arc
   let XLabel = 250;  
   const curveLength = curveDistance * 20;

   for (let y = 50; y < curveLength; y += curveDistance) {
    let mid = y + (curveDistance/2);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(XLabel, y);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(0, mid, XLabel, (y + curveDistance));
    c.stroke();
  }
}
```

The problem is the height of the canvas is limited, even if I give `height: 100%` to the `canvas` element. Here is the [JSFiddle link](https://codepen.io/yashwp/pen/NWWeMej). Please help!

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/YzzdLbP (and why did you tag this with angular...? This question is 100% CSS)

Comment: @ChrisG this question is 100% js, not CSS...css can only scale canvas but don't change canvas drawable area, to set canvas full screen just set canvas attributes `width` and `height` to window size inside tag or by JS...

Comment: @IvanKaraman That's what I did in the codepen I linked to in the same comment; it's true that this question is not strictly speaking "100% CSS" but the original iteration had a misleading title, was tagged with angular and asking about unrelated things. It still includes code that is completely irrelevant to the issue.